# How to order the coordinates generated by ToBoundaryMesh counterclockwise?

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh, sorting, order, coordinate

The following code works for polygons. A square 4x4 is tried here:

```
 << NDSolve`FEM`
a = 2;
mesh1 = ToBoundaryMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2 a, 2 a}], 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 1, "MeshOrder" -> 1];
pts = mesh1["Coordinates"]
ConvexHullMesh[pts, MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Index"}]`
ch = ConvexHull[pts];
pts[[ch]]
ConvexHullMesh[pts, MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Index"}]
```

But if part of the boundary is curved, the curved part is missed:

```
mesh2 = ToBoundaryMesh[
   RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2 a, 2 a}], 
    Disk[{2 a, 2 a}, a]], "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 1, 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1];
pts = mesh2["Coordinates"]
ConvexHullMesh[pts, MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Index"}]
pts = mesh2["Coordinates"]
ch = ConvexHullMesh[pts]
```

Comment: `mesh2` is not the convex region.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To get started:1) take [the introductory tour now](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour),2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up [by clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work),4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the list of vertex indices for lines in `mesh2`:

```
indices = mesh2["BoundaryElements"][[1, 1]];
```

Use [`FindHamiltonianPath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindHamiltonianPath.html) on the list of pairs `indices` to find a path that starts at `1` and ends at `2`:

```
hpath = FindHamiltonianPath[indices, 1, 2]
```

> ```
> {1, 28, 27, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 23, 24, 25, 26, 20, 21, 22, 13, 12, 11, 
>  10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2}
> ```

```
reIndex = AssociationThread[hpath, Range[Length @ hpath]];

BoundaryMeshRegion[mesh2["Coordinates"][[hpath]], 
 Line /@ (indices /. reIndex),
 MeshCellStyle -> {0 -> Red}, 
 MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Index"}]
```

[image]

Additional ways to get  `hpath`:

**1.** Using [`FindPath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPath.html):

```
hpath2 = First @ FindPath[indices, 1, 2];

hpath2 == hpath
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**2.** Using [`IncidenceGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IncidenceGraph.html) and the property `"VertexBoundaryConnectivity"` of `mesh2`:

```
hpath3 = FindHamiltonianPath[IncidenceGraph @ mesh2["VertexBoundaryConnectivity"], 1, 2];

hpath3 == hpath
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```

Comment: That's spectacular!!!

Comment: Dear bmf: Part of the misunderstanding is that I am new to this forum and had no idea about voting. Actually both of your answers (you and cvgmt) were useful to me. I have just upvoted both :) I also strongly agree with your comment about the contribution of kglr.

Answer (score 6):

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
a = 2;
mesh2 = ToBoundaryMesh[
   RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2 a, 2 a}], 
    Disk[{2 a, 2 a}, a]], "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 1, 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1];
mesh2["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
   "MeshElementIDStyle" -> Red]];
HighlightMesh[
 BoundaryMeshRegion[mesh2], {Style[0, Red], Labeled[0, "Index"]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, cvgmt. But points are still not correctly numbered counterclockwise.

Answer (score 6):

You could reorder coordinates:

```
ch = BoundaryMeshRegion[mesh2];

order = FindCycle[MeshConnectivityGraph[ch, {0, 0}]][[1, All, 1, 2]];

ind = AssociationThread[order -> Range[MeshCellCount[ch, 0]]];

BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[ch][[order]], 
 MeshCells[ch, 1] /. ind, MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Index"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and easy but unfortunately for my version 10, the function "MeshConnectivityGraph"  does not work.

Answer (score 5):

This is based on the answer by @cvgmt.

Is this roughly what you were looking for?

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
a = 2;
mesh2 = ToBoundaryMesh[
   RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2 a, 2 a}], 
    Disk[{2 a, 2 a}, a]], "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 1, 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1];
mesh2["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "MeshElements", 
   "MeshElementIDStyle" -> Red]];
HighlightMesh[
 BoundaryMeshRegion[mesh2], {Style[1, Red], Labeled[1, "Index"]}]
```

[image: mesh2]

Comment: The order of numbers are now ok but they are shown as labels for elements not nodes. As I have said before, there is nothing wrong with the result by cvgmt except that my version of Mathematica does not have the function "MeshConnectivityGraph"

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Just a clarification. I never implied that there's something wrong with the answer provided by @cvgmt. I have upvoted that and your question as well. I just saw the comment you left underneath said question, and thought to offer my help; thus re-arranged the numbers. I have even cited that particular answer to the response I gave. Anyway, if you and/or cvgmt are offended, I am happy to delete my reply. No worries. Please, do take into consideration that `MeshConnectivityGraph` is not used in this approach. I believe you confused yourself a bit with the other answer.